# SwiftUI views fail to render when using certain modifiers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm having some strange SwiftUI issues in a widget I'm building.

1. Applying opacity to `Text` results in the `Text` not being rendered

```
  Text("hello")
    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    .opacity(0.4)
```

The above code fails to render (in preview and on simulator) for my widget target. It renders fine in a Playground.

2. Applying trim to a `Circle` results in the `Circle` not being rendered

```
  Circle()
    .trim(from: 0.1, to: 0.5)
```

Again, the above code fails to render (in preview and on simulator) for my widget target. It renders fine in a Playground.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this. I'm using Xcode 12.3

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is an issue specific to my machine. My colleague, who is also using Xcode 12.3 can see the views rendered correctly. I've tried to simply delete and reinstall Xcode, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Yet another swiftui bug.

Comment: I have an alternative solution for text, try this ```Text("SOME TEXT").foregroundColor(.green).shadow(color: .white, radius: 0, x: 0, y: 0).opacity(0.5)```

Comment: @RajaKishan that works! nice workaround. But I *shouldn't* have to do that.

Comment: Yes. That's why I have not posted the answer. Try to find another solution. I think it's like a bug.

Comment: If you have a workaround for the Circle trimming, that would be great too ;)

Comment: Have you tried using a different simulator? Or perhaps creating a new instance of the simulator you were using? It could be something in the simulator that is used to generate the preview.

Comment: @Valdimar I think you may be right there. There are no issues when I build on a real device either. So I do think it's a simulator issue. May try reinstalling them all as it I haven't found a sim yet that does render correctly.